# how to throw a react-alert inside of a function in a class based component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Using react-alert module for alerts
My code looks like this -
index.js:

```
const options = {
    // you can also just use 'bottom center'
    position: positions.TOP_CENTER,
    timeout: 5000,
    offset: '30px',
    type: types.ERROR,
    // you can also just use 'scale'
    transition: transitions.FADE
  }
ReactDOM.render(<AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...options}>
    <App /></AlertProvider>, document.getElementById('root'));
```

App.js

```
class App extends React.Component { //then my state, functions, constructors,
//here is the problem
nextClicked = (e) => {
    if (//something) {
      if (//something) {

      const alert = useAlert();
      alert.show("ERROR MESSAGE!!!");
  }
} // etc
export default withAlert()(App)
```

Basically, I am getting the error
Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
See https://reactjs.org/warnings/invalid-hook-call-warning.html for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [their docs](https://github.com/schiehll/react-alert), it says you can use it with a higher order-component. So, if you 
import the withAlert module from react-alert, you can wrap your component when you export it. Again, check the docs on github, this is covered.

Converting the example from the docs to a class component, you get:

```js
import React from 'react'
import { withAlert } from 'react-alert'

class App extends React.component {
   constructor(props) {
    super(props);
  }
  render { 
  return (
  <button
    onClick={() => {
      this.props.alert.show('Oh look, an alert!')
    }}
  >
    Show Alert
  </button>
  )
 }
}

export default withAlert()(App)
```

Because you wrap the component in the [HOC](https://reactjs.org/docs/higher-order-components.html), you get access to the *alert* prop.

Comment: I tried changing the code to wrapping the export default class App to withAlert()(App) and defining App with class App extends React.Component ({ alert }) => {, and that gives a syntax error. I am not sure how to define app so that alert is given. Again, the docs wraps App and then it is a function based component

Comment: Can you edit your question to show what it looks like now? As long as you are not using the hook you should be fine using a class component. Nothing about the implementation has to change, you just can't use the hook inside a class component

Comment: The syntax error is the arrow. Don't use the arrow function when declaring a class component

Comment: Still unclear on what to change to get it to work, I erased the changes I made to the declaration of class App to remove the syntax error, but then alert is undefined

Comment: Without seeing your whole app component, the way it is now, I cannot tell you what you need to change

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I used the alert as a props on the function!